# top.location.href is not loading properly for chrome and safari like mozilla and IE 11

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, google-chrome

Issue is in chrome and safari browsers:- 
I have one `main.jsp`, from that i have opened one popup. in popup, i am changing the `top.location.href` to some other `jsp`. after assigning the new url to the window page is not loaded with new url till my end of the code so window is closing.(only in chrome not loading with new url but Firefox and IE11 is working fine)

`main.jsp` code -->

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = 'popuppage.jsp';
 var newwindow = window.open(url,'name','height=400,width=750');
</script>
```

`popuppage.jsp` code -->

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   top.location.href = "newpage.jsp";
    //have some logic for other usecases.
    window.close();
</script>
```

Is it possible to avoid executing the code after top.location.href=URL ?

return will not because it is not inside any function.

is it possible to load the new url before reaching `window.close()`? because `window.close()` is also needed for some other usecases.
or 
is it possible to know any new url(status going to load with new url) is assigned to `top.location.href`?

I have tried with following methods also `reload(true)`, `assign()`, `replace()`, top.location but nothing is working.

Comment: Try replacing `top.location` with `window.top.location`.